# Connection Reset after sending mempool message

Tags: network, testnet, nodes, mempool, message

I build a python script to talk to bitcoin test nodes. When I'm sending mempool messages, my connection is getting is reset.
Also sometimes when connecting to Jimmy Song's testnet node (testnet.programmingbitcoin.com) I get and an inv message back, other times my connection is cut after sending a mempool message.

What's going on here? Is mempool mostly unsupported on testnet nodes?

Comment: I've got a hunch only nodes with services 1036/1036 allow mempool messages.

Comment: It’s just not supported on modern nodes, it serves little to no purpose for anything other than abuse.